# Montar uma regua em javascript com array

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, react-native

Preciso montar uma régua igual ao desenho. Estou tendo dificuldades para encontrar uma lógica então gostaria de uma ajuda.

**Cenário**:

Existe dois arrays (um com os dados de temperatura  e outro com dados da pressão). Preciso converter esses dois arrays em duas escalas com intervalos diferentes, porém os dois são dependentes.

> **Exemplo: -90 °C = 0.5 bar(a).**

Estou usando o `react-native-svg` para desenhar a regua, esse é o único componente que funciona no framework que estou usando (React Native para mobile).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já fizeste alguma coisa ou ainda estás a começar do zero?

Comment: Eu ja fiz algumas coisas. Estou usando uma base .json para popular a regua. Voce pode ver a base no link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0By3w49HPA-yGenV3TlRIaTRxYjQ. A escala que estou fazendo eu postei uma imagem no link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0By3w49HPA-yGZGpNekIzOTJJRms